# How to remove a specific number of matching entries from a dataframe?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have two data frames:

```
subset <- data.frame(id=rep(1,7), country=c("CH", "CH", "CA", "DE", "FR", "AT", "DE"))

> subset
  id country
1  1      CH
2  1      CH
3  1      CA
4  1      DE
5  1      FR
6  1      AT
7  1      DE

whotoremove <- data.frame(id = c(1,1), country = c("DE", "FR"))

> whotoremove
  id country
1  1      DE
2  1      FR
```

I want to remove from `subset` the elements from `whotoremove`, not just by matches, but also by the number of times that they occur. That is to say, I'd like to get something like:

```
> subset
  id country
1  1      CH
2  1      CH
3  1      CA
6  1      AT
7  1      DE
```

Please notice the row names: I'd like to keep the ones from the original subset, because I need them further on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution with `dplyr` is:

```
library(dplyr)

whotoremove <- whotoremove %>% 
  group_by(id, country) %>% 
  mutate(count = 1:n()

subset %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  group_by(id, country) %>% 
  mutate(count = 1:n()) %>% 
  anti_join(whotoremove, by = c("id", "country", "count")) 

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id, country [?]
#   rowname    id country count
#   <chr>   <dbl> <fct>   <int>
# 1 1          1. CH          1
# 2 2          1. CH          2
# 3 3          1. CA          1
# 4 6          1. AT          1
# 5 7          1. DE          2
```

To preserve the rownames, I use the `rownames_to_column`-function and to remove the matching rows, I use `anti_join`. To only remove the number of times the combination occurs, I first introduce a `count`-variable and at them as a column to merge on in the `anti_join`.

Answer (score 2):

```
idx <- match(whotoremove$country, subset$country)
subset[-idx, ]
```

**Output is:**

```
  id country
1  1      CH
2  1      CH
3  1      CA
6  1      AT
7  1      DE
```

**Sample data:**

```
subset <- data.frame(id=rep(1,7), country=c("CH", "CH", "CA", "DE", "FR", "AT", "DE"))
whotoremove <- data.frame(id = c(1,1), country = c("DE", "FR"))
```